# angularjs - undefined error from input text field

Tags: angularjs

Trying to initialize text input box for user input but getting error. $scope can set intext when uncommentted. I've hacked around this (sort of) but I'm missing something basic as usual.

Console error starts: 'Error: $scope.intext is undefined' unless I assign a value. The input box is exclusively for user input. Also noticed I can assign 'why' and don't get the error until I try to split.

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('TextScreen', ['$scope', function($scope) { 
        //$scope.intext = "what";
        var why = $scope.intext.split('-');
}]);
```

html

```
<div id="cont" ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="TextScreen">
    <input type="text" ng-model="intext" />
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want to do something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/JFX23/ ?

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that `$scope.intext` is undefined. `intext`.

It is unclear what you are trying to do but I would suggest initializing `intext` or moving your code to a function. Like this:

```
$scope.change = function() {
   var why = $scope.intext.split('-');
};
```

**html**

```
<input type="text" ng-model="intext" ng-change="change()" />
```

Like suggested in angular documentation here:

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngChange

Or try using `ng-init`

```
ng-init="intext= 'demo'"
```

**Sample**

```
 <input type="text" ng-model="intext" ng-init="intext= 'demo'" />
```

O

Comment: Thanks for getting back! ng-change evaluates immediately according to the docs so for user input won't that trigger with each character? I hacked it by initializing the variable. I need something like onchange as the text string is to be evaluated after a user click. Feeling like I should stay jQuery / native javascript free at least until I understand the angular way.

Answer (score 1):

The

```
var why = $scope.intext.split('-');
```

is being processed immediately, but at that moment, `$scope.intext` is undefined, therefore you cannot call `.split` on it.

If you are trying to act on the value the user enters, you should place a watch on it

```
$scope.$watch('intext', function(oldvalue, newvalue){ 
  if(angular.isDefined(newvalue) && newvalue != oldvalue) //ensuring undefined should not processed
    var why = newvalue.split('-'); 
});
```